# Instantiate a .Net class from IronPython without boilerplate

Tags: python-import, ironpython

To use a class from the .Net host application in IronPython, you can do this:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('MyApplication')
from MyApplication import MyClass

x = MyClass()
```

But how can I do it without the first 3 lines or perhaps somehow executing them in the host application before it runs the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add classes to the scope just like variables with `SetVariable`. In VB.Net:

```
Dim engine As Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine()
Dim scope As Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope = engine.CreateScope()
scope.SetVariable("MyClass", IronPython.Runtime.Types.DynamicHelpers.GetPythonTypeFromType(GetType(MyClass)))
Dim source As Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(pathToScript)
source.Execute(scope)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting` (which is part of the dynamic language runtime used in IronPython) you have the concept of a [ScriptScope](https://github.com/IronLanguages/dlr/blob/master/Src/Microsoft.Scripting/Hosting/ScriptScope.cs) on which you can execute statements or source scripts.

This allows you to execute the boilerplate on a scope before executing the actual script. The following sample shows the basic idea:

```py
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
var scope = engine.CreateScope();

var boilerplateSourceText = @"import clr
clr.AddReference('MyApplication')
from MyApplication import MyClass
";

var boilerplateSource = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(boilerplateSourceText, SourceCodeKind.Statements);
boilerplateSource.Execute(scope);

var scriptSource = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("x = MyClass()", SourceCodeKind.Statements);
scriptSource.Execute(scope);
```